# Count XML Elements and Check if nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

Is there a way to quickly check how many of a certain element there are on an xml file?

And/or check if an element does not exist on the xml file?

Thanks

Comment: What data are you receiving in XML? In my case i am getting the database records and first i send xml request to count the data and then in second request get all data. will it be work in your case?

Comment: Have you got an example you could share?

Comment: Like you are receiving the customers table records in xml. then first send query as SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers. you have count now. Then send query in xml as SELECT * FROM customers. This is how you can get the count of data in xml you are going to fetch.